# How can i use keras model in other python file? at django

Tags: python, django, keras

Loading model is so slow, so I'm loading model in settings.py.  Then I'm reusing the model in other file, and model is not loaded.

but I'm getting the following error:

```
"Tensor Tensor("predictions/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph"
```

Many people say this error is similar to the one that happens when 
it's used in a context manager:

```
with graph.as_default():
```

and

```
with sess.as_default():
```

but that didn't work for me and I guess that answer works for loading model in multi threaded case.

I really appreciate if you can help me plz..

part of my code is below

```
*****settings.py/the file where to load the models***** 

from keras.models import load_model

GMODEL = load_model(MODEL_ROOT +'/MobileNetV2(full).h5') 

*****function.py/the file where to reuse the models***** 

from django.conf import settings 

model = settings.GMODEL
```

Comment: can you provide some code sample?

Comment: sorry i just now add my part of code